# How to dispose Image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I create a list and set it's datatemplete as Image.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="411" Margin="45,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="336">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImgSource}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

then I load 100 pictures

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<test> lstTest = new List<test>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            test t = new test();
                t.ImgSource = @"d:\test\1.jpg";
            lstTest.Add(t);
        }

    }

    private void btnHead_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox.ItemsSource = lstTest;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lstTest = null;
        listBox.ItemsSource = null;
    }

    public class test
    {
        public string ImgSource { get; set; }


    }

}
```

before I click btnHead,the mem is 20m, and when I click this button, the mem increase to 40m. 
I want to create a function to release mem (return 20m), but btnClear_Click do not work.
How to dispose Image in wpf?

Comment: It is a common mistake to think that setting something a reference variable to `null` does anything in terms of freeing memory. This line does nothing: `lstTest = null;`. Try to remove all entries from the list and let the garbage collector to its work.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar thx, but I've try to use `lstTest.Clear()` and `lstTest.Remove()`  it was still do not work.

Comment: WPF usually caches bitmaps that are created from URIs. Although I'm not sure if this also applies to local file URIs (as in your example), a safe way to avoid caching would be to explicitly load a BitmapImage from a stream, e.g. a FileStream. You could do this in a Converter in the `ImgSource` binding.